# How to add custom field in order_sales table and used it?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom-field

i need to add new field in order_sale tables.

I create a initialSchema and add field in database (office_id). But i don't use this filed in order create, no matter where it is created.

Please tell me how to use this field, on order save. Google's results are very confusing .

Please do not answer me with things like EAV or attributes.

This should be the table and should be used there.

I have a specific question, I hope for get a clear and precise answer.

Comment: what do you want a new custom column should be on order admin grid and also you can save it to database?

Comment: I need this when orders is crated. no matter where it is created